# Deploying Azure sentinel analytics rules in bulk with Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, automation

I am trying to deploy around 70 log analytics rules in to an environment's Azure Sentinel with Powershell so I don't have to do this manually one by one. I got the Analyticsrules.ps1 and rules.json which includes all the rules I want to deploy.

When I run it, I get this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nz9S4.png

**"Cannot bind argument to parameter 'path' because it is null"**

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I can show the json file as well but its really long.

Comment: The source code for "Analyticsrules.ps1" is in this link for reference: https://github.com/javiersoriano/sentinelascode/blob/master/Scripts/CreateAnalyticsRules.ps1

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the error, the path parameter is null.

Please make sure `$env:Pipeline_Workspace` and `$artifactPath` are not null.

```
$artifactPath = Join-Path $env:Pipeline_Workspace $artifactName 
$rulesFilePath = Join-Path $artifactPath $RulesFile
```

Comment: Hi Joy, Thanks for the repsonse. What do you suggest the line to be to not make it null?

Comment: @rk3 Just test to `Write-Output` the values to make sure they are not null.